# ng-options in select returning an Object instead of String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to learn Angular and I'm in the very basic steps. I've searched about this but could not find anything that could help me.

I'm having a problem with the ng-options. When I hit the button that triggers `addSword(sword)`, I'm expecting it to insert `$scope.elems.object.name` into `{{sword.elem}}` but instead, I'm receiving `$scope.elems.object`.
Better explained, `sword.elem` is showing `{"name":"Water" , "beats":"Fire"}` instead of just `'Water'`. I can use `sword.elem.elem`, but I can see that there is something wrong here.

Something strange: my Select Menu is showing the proper value.

Thanks for any help and sorry if there is some answer about this and I could not find.

index.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="sword in swords">
    <td>{{sword.name}}</td>
    <td>{{sword.attack}}</td>
    <td>{{sword.desc}}</td>
    <td>{{sword.elem.name}}</td>
</tr>
...
<select class="form-control" ng-model="sword.elem" 
    ng-options="elem.name for elem in elems">
    <option value="">Selecione uma elem</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addSword(sword)" 
    ng-disabled="!sword.name || !sword.elem || !sword.attack">Add Sword</button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.elems = [
    {name: "Fire", beats: "Earth"},
    {name: "Water", beats: "Fire"}
];

$scope.addSword = function(sword){
        $scope.swords.push(angular.copy(sword));
        delete $scope.sword;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I've tried somethings. Read the Angular Docs and could not figure out either.

What I want is to pass the ng-options selection into the ng-model 'sword-elem'. The ng-options selection is being feeded by two objects:

```
        $scope.elems = [
        {name: "Fire", beats: "Earth"},
        {name: "Water", beats: "Fire"}
    ];
```

I want my ng-model='sword.elem' to receive $scope.elems.name.
After my Form gets submitted, the following object is created:

```
{"name":"Stack Question",
"attack":"66",
"desc":"You shall answer this sword.",
"elem": {"name":"Fire","beats":"Earth"}
}
```

But I'm trying to receive the something like this:

```
{"name":"Stack Question",
"attack":"66",
"desc":"You shall answer this sword.",
"elem": "Fire"}
}
```

My current workaround is to print {{sword.elem.name}} instead of just {{sword.elem}}.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to add the selected sword to your list of swords. You'll need to use [ngOptions select As](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)

Markup:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="sword" 
    ng-options="elem as elem.name for elem in elems">
    <option value="">Selecione uma elem</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addSword(sword)" 
    ng-disabled="!sword">Add Sword</button>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/70Uif1p7GPNmU8Fw9iHn?p=preview)

Comment: This is the same code that I'm using, except that the model is 'sword' instead of 'sword.elem'. With this, I'll bind my whole form to submit only the select input. Anyway, tried it and got bugged. Thanks, anyway. :/

Comment: @RodrigoSouza look closer, it's not the same.  `elem as elem.name for` vs just `elem.name for`.  you could continue to use `sword.elem` in the `ng-model`.

Comment: @Claies, thanks. My bad. I've changed that piece of code. Same result.